# Animate individual observable elements from another component position

Tags: angular, animation, rxjs

I would like to animate multiple elements from a starting position to an end position in an individual sequence (when `card0` finishes, `card1` should start). The starting position element is defined in a different Angular component. The cards are defined in an `Observable` element and are currently displayed at the same time when you click the button.

In the image you can see that `card0` should move from `start` to the bottom `card0` element. After that, the same should happen with `card1`, then with `card2`

[image]

I currently only managed to animate the observable elements. I would like to find out how to animate them individually and how to let them flow from a starting position from the other component.

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ajnomj?file=src/app/second.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a bit complex because to move a tag from a position to another you need know the position initial and final.

Imagine you has an animation like:

```
  animations:[
    trigger('move',[
      transition('false => true',[
      style({ 'top': 0,'left':0 }),
      animate('200ms', style({top:'*',left:'*'})),
    ])])
  ]
```

This animation "move" the element from the position absolute 0,0 to the position absolute that the element has really. But we don't want the element with `style={position:absolute}`. So we need calculate. To calculate, we are going to get the elements in a ViewChildren and use a variable to position

```
@ViewChildren('card') cards:QueryList<ElementRef>
pos:any[]=[]
```

And when animation start, we are going to calculate the position of the elements.

```
  startAnimation(){
    this.pos=this.cards.map(x=>{
      const rect=x.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      return {
         top:(window.scrollY+rect.top)+'px',
         left:(window.scrollX+rect.left)+'px',
         position:'absolute'
      }
    })
    this.count=0;
  }
```

Then we are going to use a variable "count", and when a animation is done increment the variable

```
  animationDone(incr:number)
  {
    this.count+=incr
    if (this.count>3) //<--if the variable is the last animation
      this.pos=this.pos.map(x=>null)  //<--we equal to null the array "pos"
  }
```

Use visibility hidden and visibility visible, makes the "trick"

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of obs$ | async; let i = index">
    <div
      #card
      [ngStyle]="pos[i] || null"
      [style.visibility]="i <= count ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"
      [@move]="count == i"
      (@move.done)="animationDone(count == i ? 1 : 0)"
    >
      {{ item }}
    </div>
```

You can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xr5y3h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: See this "strange" `[@move.done]="animationDone(count == i ? 1 : 0)"`, only pass to the function 1 when count==i, else Angular execute so many times elements has the observable

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I really didn't know where to start but this puts me on the right track and your Stackblitz is very helpful!